# JavaScript Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

```
out += (out ? rogueArray[14] : rogueArray[13]) + arrayItem + ((vanWilder[arrayItem] !== null) ? = + encodeURIComponent(vanWilder[arrayItem]) : rogueArray[13]);
```

There is supposedly a syntax error here on the line up until [arrayItem in Dreamweaver. Any help?

Here is image of it in DreamWeaver:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITqV3.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking down what you've written...

```
out += (
    out ?
        rogueArray[14] :
        rogueArray[13]
    ) +
    arrayItem +
    (
        (vanWilder[arrayItem] !== null) ?
        //Oh no! What's this assignment doing here?
        = + encodeURIComponent(vanWilder[arrayItem]) : rogueArray[13]);
```

As well, it would be easier to debug your code if you did something like the following:

```
if (out) {
    out += rogueArray[14]
} else {
    out += rogueArray[13]
}
out += arrayItem

if (vanWilder[arrayItem] !== null) {
    out += encodeURIComponent(vanWilder[arrayItem])
} else {
    out += rogueArray[13]
}
```

Comment: +1 @NT3RP for getting those ternary operators out of there. Code should be written to be *read*. Save the ternaries for minification, obfuscation, and pluralizing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what  ? = +  means, but really, that's too much going on in one line if you're just writing this. Break it apart into separate lines, use temporary variables, and then refactor it down to a compact one liner with nested tertiary operators if you really need to after it works, doing this one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You have an assignment operator floating around in the middle of that expression. Remove it and it should be syntactically correct.